# Spider doesn't want to scrape the next page

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

My spider doesn't want to go to the next page for some reason. It doesn't give me any errors but scraped the only page.
I have code that is similar to this but another site, and it worked fine.

```py
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy import Request
class JobsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'jobs'
    allowed_domains = ['https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/egr']
    start_urls = ['https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/egr/']

    def parse(self, response):
        jobs = response.css(".result-info")
        for job in jobs:
            Dates = response.css(".result-date").extract_first()
            Titles = job.css('.hdrlnk::text').extract_first()
            address = job.css(".result-hood::text").extract_first()
            relative_url = job.css(".hdrlnk::attr('href')").extract_first()
            yield{
                "Date": Dates,
                "Title": Titles,
                "Address": address,
                "Link": relative_url
            }


        url = response.xpath('//*[@id="searchform"]/div[5]/div[3]/span[2]/a[3]/@href').extract_first()
        absurl = response.urljoin(url)
        if url:

            yield Request(url=absurl, callback=self.parse)
        else:
            print("No next page found")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the `allowed_domains` too strict, and therefor the new urls will not be allowed based on the "domain".

So simply change

```
allowed_domains = ['https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/egr']
```

To

```
allowed_domains = ['craigslist.org']
```